# React static website with Firestore, trouble exporting to CSV

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

To start, I am new to javascript, react, and firestore :) so forgive me if I've butchered this whole thing.  I have read a number of other questions on here about firestore data to csv but they didn't solve my problems.  I am working on an azure staticly hosted react website that will list out the users on individual cards (this is done), provide a form to make queries based on date within the card (this is done), and then use the data it gets back to fill/download a CSV file all within the browser (where I am stuck).

My data structure:

```
Collection "users"
-Document "User"
--name
--email
--Collection "game_days"
---Document "GameDay"
----date
----notes
----games_played // this is an array ie: [{"hours": 4, "game": "NHL 93"}, {"game": "FF10", "hours": 3}]
Collection "video_games"
-game_name
-producer
```

When I query the database with db.collectionGroup("game_days") after getting a snapshot of a user document, I have been trying to put that into a csv file, ideally with the dates along the headers and the game as the key, with hours listed in the corresponding location.

I can't even get to formatting the csv though because I am having trouble working with the returned query data.  Currently, I'm pushing new objects into an array, and the result is what almost looks like json with all of the information I want inside... I just can't seem to get it into a format where I can extract the data.

My component code:

```
function custom_csv2(objArray) {
    console.log(objArray)
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','

            line += array[i][index];
        }

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    console.log(str)
}
const UserDataQuery = ( {user_id} ) => {
     let uid_start = "start"+user_id //concatenating user id on the end to identify the input field from form
     let uid_end = "end"+user_id
     const get_user_data = e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let j_array = []
                let coll_name = "users/" + user_id + "/game_days"
                let start_date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(document.getElementById(uid_start).value));
                let end_date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(document.getElementById(uid_end).value));
                db.collection(coll_name).where("timestamp", ">", start_date).where("timestamp", "<", end_date)
                    .get()
                    .then( function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                        let user_data = JSON.stringify(doc.data())
                        setTimeout(j_array.push(user_data), 1000) //allow time for the query to process
                    });
                }).then(custom_csv2(j_array));
    return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="start date">Start Date</label>
                    <input 
                    type="date"
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                    id={uid_start}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="end date">End Date</label>
                    <input
                    type="date"
                    className="form-control"
                    id={uid_end}
                    placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                    />
                </div>
                <button className="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick={get_user_data}>
                Submit
                </button>
            </form>
          )
      }
```

The first console.log in my function custom_csv2 outputs:

```
0: "{"date":"6-2-2020","timestamp":{"seconds":1591070400,"nanoseconds":0},"notes":"gecko shmecko","games_played":[{"hours":9,"game":"Gilded Gecko"}]}"
1: "{"date":"6-12-2020","games_played":[{"hours":3,"game":"Gilded Gecko"}],"timestamp":{"seconds":1591934400,"nanoseconds":0},"notes":""}"
2: "{"date":"6-16-2020","notes":"nice","timestamp":{"seconds":1592280000,"nanoseconds":0},"games_played":[{"game":"Funnest Game","hours":12}]}"
3: "{"notes":"","games_played":[{"hours":6,"game":"Gilded Gecko"},{"game":"NHL 93","hours":2},{"hours":4.5,"game":"FF10"},{"game":"Funnest Game","hours":0.5}],"date":"06-17-2020","timestamp":{"seconds":1592366400,"nanoseconds":0}}"
4: "{"date":"06-18-2020","timestamp":{"seconds":1592452800,"nanoseconds":0},"tasks":[{"hours":2,"game":"NHL 93"},{"hours":12,"game":"Funnest Game"},{"hours":6,"game":"FF10"},{"hours":1,"game":"Gilded Gecko"}],"notes":"nicuuu"}"
5: "{"timestamp":{"seconds":1592452800,"nanoseconds":0},"notes":"lunch","date":"6-18-2020","games":[{"hours":12,"game":"FF10"}]}"
```

The second console log just outputs an empty string.

I feel like I'm so close to being able to do what I want yet so far away... if I try to stringify the array it returns an empty string because it's full of objects I think, and if I try to turn the array to an object (ie: `let j_array = {}`) then I can't .push() to it.  I also just tried pushing `doc.data()` to the array without stringifying it first, but that appeared harder to work with than the stringified version. I also have tried to iterate through the j_array and do things like make rows with the data based on index in the array but it just doesn't seem to do anything during the iteration.  I've had trouble working with the firestore objects a little bit, mostly I've just used json via REST apis before, coding in python.  So I don't know if I'm just a noob or what I'm missing, or if the data could be structured better, it was created when designing the app which uploads the data to firestore.

Any suggestions or advice on how to work with the firestore data to be able to get it formatted into a csv would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was missing 2 things.

1.

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
// try to stringify or something, and then push to an array
}
```

was a waste of time, I just needed (in updated ES6)

```
querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
  id: doc.id,
  ...doc.data()
  }).then(function (result) {
  custom_csv(result)
})
```

The `.then(function (result)...` was what allowed me to really work with the data.

2. I needed to completely reformat the data before sending it into a csv generator.  I ended up using export-to-csv.  I gave it one array to use as the headers (dates), and another array of arrays which it filled in each row as one of the arrays (I gave it an array with each game being it's own array, values were the hours played in the same order as the dates/headers).